# ffmpeg alphamerge two videos into a gif with transparent background

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I had [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1647590/have-ffmpeg-merge-a-matte-key-file-over-the-normal-video-file-removing-the-backg) answered that helped me merge two mp4 videos with alphamerge with the following command to an .mov file

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i mask.mp4 -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[mask][main];[main][mask]alphamerge" -c:v qtrle output.mov
```

Now, I was wondering how I would change this for the output of a gif.  When I tried

```
ffmpeg -i word.mp4 -i word.matte.mp4 -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[mask][main];[main][mask]alphamerge" -c:v qtrle output.gif
```

I got this error

```
[swscaler @ 0x5601daaa4d40] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[gif @ 0x5601d9ad2d00] GIF muxer supports only a single video GIF stream.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

I'm using ffmpeg 4.2.4

Comment: Try the ffmpeg command in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality/556031#556031).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining your command with the command from [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/a/556031):

```
ffmpeg -i word.mp4 -i word.matte.mp4 -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[mask][main];[main][mask]alphamerge,fps=10,scale=320:-1,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

Note the removal of `-c:v qtrle`. You can't put QuickTime Animation RLE video into GIF output.

If you want a background photo combine command from [How to overlay with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/)

```
ffmpeg -i word.mp4 -i word.matte.mp4 -i background.jpg -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[mask][main];[main][mask]alphamerge[fg];[2][fg]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:format=auto,fps=10,scale=320:-1,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

Comment: Thanks again @llogan! I'll award the bounty once it lets me.  Once again I'm unsure it's out of the scope of this question, but would I have to do a third input to change the background to a image/color instead of making it transparent, say a background of paris or something

Comment: @nadermx See updated answer